# How to remove empty strings from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to remove empty strings from a list:

```
['""', 'live', '""', '""']
```

Using code:

```
list = [ele for ele in list if ele.strip()]
        print(list)
```

Output:

```
['""', 'live', '""', '""']
```

Wanted result:

```
['live']
```

Comment: The input strings aren't empty. They have double quote characters in them. If you want to remove these, you will need to adjust the `if` condition to check for strings with double quotes, too.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Amazing! Thank you for letting me notate that. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 3):

This is not empty string, it is `'""'`, try this:

```
lst = ['""', 'live', '""', '""']
res = [ele for ele in lst if ele != '""']
print(res)
```

**Update** Check and remove empty string too -> (**`''`**)

```
lst = ['""', 'live', '""', '""', '', '']
res = [ele for ele in lst if not ele in ['""', '']]
print(res)
```

---

```
['live']
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the strings in your list are empty. Try this as input instead:

```
['', 'live', '']
```

Your code will give the correct output in this case.

If you also want to remove strings such as `'""'`, you will have to adjust the `if` condition to do so.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your effort Sir.

Answer (score 0):

As [Code-Apprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1440565/code-apprentice) mentioned, they are not empty values in your list but you can filter the list as follows:

```
sample_list = ['""', 'live', '""', '""']
sample_list = list(filter(('""').__ne__, sample_list))
```

Comment: `('""').__ne__` is very... iffy, even though it might be tempting to not use a lambda. Still, maybe `lambda e: e != '""'` ? However, neither will remove **actual** empty strings...